# Why are NiMH batteries venting with <200mA load?

Tags: batteries, nimh

I have built a custom NiMH battery pack/charger/controller that has two 2000mAh batteries wired in series. It has a boost converter that outputs 5V to a USB connector through a 500mA fuse.

It seems to work as expected, except when I connect a 1W LED board (with a PAM2804 constant current driver set to 125mA) to the output there is smoke/vapor apparently from the batteries after about 5 seconds. I have tried new batteries from different manufacturers with the same result.

Should most NiMH batteries be able to handle this amount of current? What could be the cause of venting from the batteries?

Charger/boost converter:

[image: charger]

LED driver:

[image: led driver]

PAM2804 datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM2804.pdf

XT1861 datasheet: http://www.natlinear.com/uploadfiles/2014/XT/XT1861_E.pdf

LM317 datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the individual cell voltages? Does both vent?

Comment: are you sure the load is 200mA?

Comment: also seems slightly wasteful to have two converters in series

Comment: @winny I took the batteries out and measured 1.26V and 1.24V. I haven't been able to determine whether it's one or both that are venting.

Comment: @user253751 When tested with an in-line USB ammeter the reading is actually 50mA, but that may not be accurate.

Comment: They should not vent at that voltage. Try to capture it when venting, probably by logging it.

Comment: well 200mA is 0.1C which seems like a pretty normal discharge rate. Google says they can usually handle up to 3C. Perhaps you have a short circuit in the boost converter or in the battery box wiring? Perhaps you somehow wired the batteries in reverse-parallel by mistake? I notice there is a fuse on the output of the boost converter, but is there one in series with the batteries?

Comment: If the boost converter inductor was too small (I can't see which chip it is so I can't look up which value of inductor it wants) it could saturate, acting like a short circuit.

Comment: Are you supplying power to the LM317 while this is happening?

Comment: @user253751 The boost converter is a XT1861B502SR-G (datasheet link above). The inductor is PWCWAQ2012F-100KTT (10uH, 600mA, 0805).

Comment: @Finbarr I believe there was about 4V (from a 9V solar panel) at the LM317 input.

Comment: @winny Under the load, the combined battery voltage drops to 1.19V. The output of the boost converter drops to 3V.

Comment: That’s beyond depleted. You need to have an undervoltage cutoff at about 1.1 V/cell.

Comment: @winny After more experimentation I've found that this works fine when using 4 batteries in series, but not 2 or 3. Even 125mA causes venting with 2 batteries in series. Maybe I just have terrible batteries. I'll plan to use 4 batteries and add low-voltage detection and cutoff.

Comment: Good lad! Report back when you have a working solution ready so this question can be closed.